# Trying to increase the clickable area of a checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tag `<li class="pointer-cursor">abc<li>` to which i am prepending a checkbox using jQuery

```
jQuery('.pointer-cursor').prepend('<input type = checkbox>');
```

The result of this is

`<li class="pointer-cursor">
    <input type="checkbox">abc
</li>`

I want to increase the clickable area of the checkbox using jQuery so that wherever i click on the line the checkbox gets checked.

Comment: Use a `<label>` around the input then and give it a display block or something.

Comment: how do i add label tag around this using jQuery? since this is getting generated dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a label around the input to give it a larger click area.

```js
$('.pointer-cursor').each(function(){
  $(this).html('<label><input type="checkbox">'+this.innerHTML +'</label>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="pointer-cursor">abc</li>
  <li class="pointer-cursor">123</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer definitely helped. I think the solution should be along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click handler to the document to listen for click on the `li` tag and then toggle the checked state of the checkbox.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', 'li.pointer-cursor', function() {
  var input = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  input.prop('checked', !input.prop('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an **onclick** event on your listed item and an accompanying function to toggle your checkbox.

```js
function onClick(){
  let checkbox = document.getElementById('check');
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox">abc
<li onclick="onClick()">hi</li>
```